# feed data for CNN in different time

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am now learning the machine learning ,i have one question that can we feed the data to the Neural network in different time , foe example , 
today i have 10000 images to train a image recognition neural network , i get a neural network with weights1 and bias1,
tomorrow , i get another 100 images , i want to train the neural network based on the old neural network .

is this possible ?

and I think this is natural way the human recognition .

thanks very much

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,it is possible , for example search for "Online learning", in online learning you train incrementally when new data comes in. For tensorflow in specific, you can save/load your model ,and train after loading.

Comment: thanks, i want to implement such online learning using tensorflow , is there any simple way to start ?

Comment: and , i search online learning , it seems there is no too much related information , most of them is about the human learning

Comment: Its true! Almost everything its related to human learning. Take a look at this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueigGQshRm8&list=PL0Smm0jPm9WcCsYvbhPCdizqNKps69W4Z&index=106
In the case of tensorflow, i primarily use tflearn and skflow(they are 2 frameworks on the top of tensorflow), in the case  of skflow, you just specify a logdir parameter for the constructor, and this will create checkpoints and necessary files for the model, when you want to continue training, you just instantiate again the model usig the same logdir parameter and it will automatically (1/2)

Comment: load your save weights and bias, you just call "fit" again and it will continue training incrementally. For the case of tflearn, you save your model after training with model.save(directory) and then load it with model.load(directory), after you load, you just continue trianing again with fit. Take a look at this 2 frameworks, they make tensorflow easiear to adopt

Comment: actually the modern term is **not** online learning, but **continual learning**. Simply learning in "incremental"/"online" fashion does not make sure you do not forget what you learned before. Neural nets suffer from catastrophic forgetting (given new data, and trained long enough - they forget about everything you had before).